# Problems with installing Sqlite3 and Apt-get

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby, and have a problem with installing Sqlite3. After searching on the web, I found a solution, first to do :
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev

However, I am on an AWS instance which doesn't have apt-get, but only yum. Would anyone please tell me how to install apt-get on the AWS linux, or how to use yum to install libsqlite3-dev ? Really appreciate !

Scott

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact package names, but `yum` works like `apt-get`. You can list the packages with a certain name with:

```
yum search sqlite3
```

And then install, for example (I made those up):

```
yum install sqlite3-devel
yum install libsqlite3-devel
```

Note that you might have other missing libraries like `libreadline5-devel` or `libncurses5-devel`, happened to me once.

Comment: I tried "yum install sqlite-devel". It works. Thank you very much ! -Scott

Answer (score 1):

-dev versions of packages usually have -devel name in rpm based distributions. Try installing like

`yum install libsqlite3-devel`

Comment: I tried "yum install sqlite-devel". It works. Thank you very much ! Scott